# Phonegap IOS geolocation permission alert not showing

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

I'm developing an IOS app in phonegap and I want to get the user's permission for location services upon loading. The problem is that the alert asking for permission doesn't appear until I resume the app (press home and open app again) or wait a couple of minutes, which is not acceptable.

I'm using the `deviceready` event like so:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
function deviceReady() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationSuccess,
                                         onLocationError
                                         );
}
```

If I don't wait for deviceready the alert appears fine but I get double prompted with a message like this one:

`/var/mobile/Applications/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/www/index.html would like to use your current location`

Any ideas to get this working?

Comment: Have you looked at the full example given in the docs : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation They should give you an idea of how to get it working, make sure you have `<plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />` in the `config.xml`

Comment: @methodMan yes, the geolocation is working fine, but the permission alert "My app would like to use your current location" is what seems buggy, it only appears until I exit the app pressing the home button. I'm testing on my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1 btw.

Comment: I just updated to Cordova 2.3.0 (I was on 2.2) and the issue seems to be resolved. Everything works as expected now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to here it. They might be releasing 2.4.0 today so it might even be worth it to update to that. I know it's got a lot of ios fixes in it. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I have the same problem with all prompts on iOS 8. Push notification and location is not asking for permission until I close the app...

Answer (score 2):

I was fighting with this issue for few days and I finally got the solution. Seems like its not plugin nor corvoda version to blame. Try adding this **Content-Security-Policy** entry to your **index.html** inside head section:

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'
> ```
>
> data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Important part is

> default-src * gap://ready file:;

gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have solved the issue but following will help others in future.

In order to show a permission dialog on **iOS**, you have to configure below in the **config.xml**.

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
    <array>
      <string>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

I use this and it works well.

Comment: Problem is that he can see dialog but only after closing app. Your answer is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is perfect for me:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
    <array>
      <string>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Yes of course, this code put on the config.xml  because you need a especific configuration in IOS app in Android with cordoba-plugin-geolocation its perfect for this works, tell me if can I help you more.

Answer (score 0):

for the permission dialog on **iOS** use this code in your **config.xml**

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
<array>
  <string>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
</array>
```

@AAhad for your problem when the user close the dialog or alert, you can check the option is available and you can talk with the user with new alert with your request if you need to active the GPS.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
  //Code for your GPS
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object or if your user close de dialog or cancel de permission
//
function onError(error) {
        alert('Error please check your GPS on Settings: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'Please Active Your GPS' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```